# DD-WRT cannot replicate the static route Windows creates

Tags: openvpn, dd-wrt

I have a DD-WRT router that needs a static route pointing the remote adress to the local VPN adress, like this:

```
route add 192.168.1.x (remote private adress) mask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.2 (VPN server adress). (My own private adress being 192.168.2.x).
```

The VPN peers are hosted on Ubuntu 12.04 boxes behind the DD-WRT routers. I can ping both VPN and private adresses of the servers themselves, but not the subnets behind them.
That route works perfectly when applied locally on Windows, but when I try to put the same route on the DD-WRT router (which is the Windows machines gateway), it doensn't create the route on it's routing table.

Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Where is the VPN connection?  On the router on the Windows box or on another device?

Comment: Is 10.8.0.2 locally connected to the router? If not, how would it get the packets there? Also, did you mean `192.168.x.0`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers! The VPN is on the server machines, both peers are Ubuntu 12.04 boxes. Those server are both behind the DD-WRT NAT gateways, so yes, it is locally connected to the router. Yes I meant 192.168.x.0. Will improve my question.

Comment: If the VPN connection only exists between those servers the routers won't know anything about the VPN. Did you configure those servers to be able to route the traffic?

Comment: Thans for your answer Seth. Yes, they're configured to route the traffic, ip forwarding enabled and everything. As I said, what I want to do works when I do the route on Windows with command prompt, it's just that DD-WRT refuses to fix the same route on it's routing table. Already rebooted the routers, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coundn't find a solution so I just gave up.
Solved my problem with a scheduled task that executes a batch file
with the "*route add*" command on the Windows machines.